# Disable Little Snitch in guest account?

Tags: macos, firewall

It's annoying as hell to let others use your computer on a guest account with Little Snitch installed, all the consecutive popups one after another...it's really ridiculous.

Also in the event my Macbook is stolen, a user logs into guest, all the dialogs will clearly let him know to disable connections.  So little luck there using "Find my Mac."

Anyway to just disable this or set a rule to allow everything?  Of course any rules created in LS within the guest account do not save after logout.

Comment: Good use case, since Little Snitch runs at boot, you'd need a login script to kill it and would have ti live with / deal with respawning the software or just reboot after logging out the guest. Do you use fast user switching and expect LS to run on one account and leave the other alone or will the main user log out before guest logs in

Comment: Although if the point of using Little Snitch is to stop programs contacting unknown sites doesn't allowing the guest account defeat this object?

Comment: I'm not interested in fast user switching.  I just want it on in the main account and off in the guest.  Or, I would like to set rules in guest that are different than those in the main.

Comment: Perhaps I could save the Guest rules to a shared folder and they would always engage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Login to the Guest Account.
2. Disable Little Snitch Network Filter
3. Open Library > Preferences,  copy at.obdev.LittleSnitch... to a shared folder
4. Logout and Login to Main Account
5. Open Terminal and run sudo su
6. Open Library/username/Library/Preferences and overwrite file with copied file.
7. Logout and Login to Guest Account.  LS is Disabled.

Comment: Boom, just like that.

Comment: Is there any way you could expand on your answer please? I tried following the steps but I can't find the file mentioned in step 3 where it's suggested that I should be seeing it...

Comment: You may have to Option-Click on the Go To menu in Finder to access the Library folder in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 4):

@user43855's steps work correctly (except for step 6 which is missing a crucial bit), but they also assume the user is very familiar with what is being done. I have expanded to include step-by-step details for disabling Little Snitch automatically in the Guest account.

This process creates a Little Snitch preferences file where Little Snitch is disabled, and then copies that file to the `User Template` folder that is copied every time the Guest account is recreated. (Note the User Template folder is also used for the creation of new accounts, so if you want Little Snitch on in a new account, you will have to enable it after the account is created.)

1. Login to the Guest account.
2. Disable Little Snitch Network Filter in Little Snitch's settings.
3. Open Finder, and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
4. In the box labeled "Go to the folder", enter `~/Library/Preferences` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Find the file named `at.obdev.LittleSnitch.plist` and right-click on it. Chooose `Copy "at.obdev.LittleSnitch.plist"`.
6. Again press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and this time in "Go to the folder" enter `/Users/Shared/`.
7. Right-click and choose Paste Item.
8. Log out of the Guest account, and log in to your main account.
9. Open Terminal and type `sudo su` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
10. When prompted, enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
11. Type `cd "/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Library/Preferences"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
12. Type `cp /Users/Shared/at.obdev.LittleSnitch.plist ./` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
13. The next time you log in to the Guest Account, Little Snitch will be disabled.

Comment: Any new accounts created on the Mac when this process is complete will also have Little Snitch disabled. The User Template is used to create new accounts.

Comment: @pknz good call, I edited to note that.

Comment: I just tried following this tutorial and I can't find the at.obdev.LittleSnitch.plist file. There are at.obdev.LittleSnitchConfiguration.plist and two others but no sign of the file you mention. I wonder if this because I upgraded to Yosemite. Would you know a solution for this?

Comment: Use at.obdev.LittleSnitchConfiguration.plist. They likely changed the name of the file since this was last updated.